# JQuery validate shows multiple errors for the same field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have been searching for the last two days but could not find any answers. Can anyone helping me with this? I am using Jquery validate to validate my forms. The problem is it generates two errors when the input has id. I tried group as well but did not work.

Here is my code:

```
<label><input type="number" value="0" name="NAME[]" min="0" max="3" required="required"/>Some text</label>
<label><input type="number" value="0" name="NAME[]" min="0" max="3" required="required"/>Some text</label>
<label><input type="number" value="0" name="NAME[]" min="0" max="3" required="required" id="MyID"/>
```

And my Jquery:

```
rules: {
        "NAME[]": { CustomFunction: "NAME[]" },
},
messages: {
        "NAME[]": { CustomFunction: "Custom Message" },
},
```

And with groups

```
groups:
            {
                GroupName: "NAME[] MyID"
            }
```

So the problem is it generates error separately for the last one with the id of MyID which I don't want.

```
<label id="MyID-error" class="errorClass" for="MyID">Custom Message</label>
```

This is the only one I want.

```
<label id="NAME[]-error" class="errorClass" for="NAME[]">Custom Message</label>
```

Link to fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/Doorsofheaven/afoanL20/

Comment: This plugin requires each field to have a unique name, it can't deal with all the fields having the same `NAME[]` name.

Comment: Everything else works fine. I want to keep this format. The only issue I have is with the one with id.

Comment: Why are you putting an ID into `groups`? The value is supposed to be a space-separated list of element names, not IDs.

Comment: Just tried that. Doesn't work with or without groups.

Comment: Are you sure it's related to the ID? I didn't think jquery-validate did anything with IDs, it only uses names.

Comment: Yes. It generates separate errors for each one that has ID. I tried it now.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Doorsofheaven/afoanL20/

Comment: I'm not sure how the ID is related, but I think the problem is with your custom validator. It will get called separately for each input. But it's not just validating that one input, it validates them all collectively. So if there's an error, it will return an error for each input, and your error placement appends each error message.

Comment: As Barmar already stated, you cannot have the same `name` on more than one `input`.  Also, @Barmar is correct, the jQuery Validate plugin does not care about the `id`.